# Sort multiple columns in csv including date stored as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sort, csv

I am attempting to sort data stored in a csv.

My data is as below:

```
name,date,time
DEF,01/02/2021,06:00
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:50
```

*(date stored as dd/mm/yyyy)

I am trying to Sort by name then date then time, I've tried various combinations but unable to figure it out.

Using `sort -t, -k1 -k2,3 -u >> $report` arranges in name in ascending order but unable to get the same for the remaining two columns.

UPDATE:*Apologies, it had been along day, not sure why i had used a table*

Comment: Please reformat the data in the question the way it's represented in your data file. This makes it possible to actually test solutions.

Comment: Can you change your date format to `YYYY-mm-dd`? That will make sorting _much_ easier.

Comment: @glennjackman If the file is a proper CSV formatted file (which we don't know), `csvsort` (from csvkit) would easily sort it on the date field given a simple `strptime` format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with `csvsort`, but it seems to want to rewrite the date and time fields:

```bsh
$ csvsort --date-format '%d/%m/%Y' -c date,time file
name,date,time
HIJ,2021-01-31,0:07:50
ABC,2021-02-01,0:05:50
DEF,2021-02-01,0:06:00
```

Here, `csvsort` from [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) is used to sort the data on the 2nd and 3rd fields (by name).  The 2nd field is a date field and we provide a format string describing it with `--date-format`.  See `man strptime` for what format strings are valid on your system.

Comment: It seems to be interpreting the input time format as `%M:%S` not `%H:%M`

Comment: Hmm... yes. Usually, the date+time is kept as a single field, but that's obviously not done here, possibly (we still haven't seen the actual data).  Also note that the want to sort on the name first, which means all the juggling with the dates becomes unnecessary for the given data as the names are unique.  In fact, a simple `sort file` would solve it for the given data.

Answer (score 3):

Using miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), and starting from

```
name,date,time
DEF,01/02/2021,06:00
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:40
```

and formatting date and time properly, and then sorting

```
mlr --csv put -S '$tmp=strptime(($date." ".$time), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")' \
then sort -f name,tmp \
then cut -x -f tmp ./input.csv>./output.csv
```

you will have

```
+------+------------+-------+
| name | date       | time  |
+------+------------+-------+
| ABC  | 01/02/2021 | 05:40 |
| ABC  | 01/02/2021 | 05:50 |
| DEF  | 01/02/2021 | 06:00 |
| HIJ  | 31/01/2021 | 07:50 |
+------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```bsh
$ cat file
DEF,01/02/2021,06:00
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:50
```

then this sorts by datetime (year+month+day+time), increasing

```bsh
sort -t, -k2.7,2.10n -k2.4,2.5n -k2.1,2.2n -k3,3 file
```

```
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:50
DEF,01/02/2021,06:00
```

The `-k` option is specified as

> ‘-k POS1[,POS2]’

> Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between
> POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted),
> *inclusive*.
> ...
> each POS has the form ‘F[.C][OPTS]’, where F is the
> number of the field to use, and C is the number of the first
> character from the beginning of the field.  Fields and character
> positions are numbered starting with 1

---

With a header row in the file, we have a bit extra shell syntax:

```bsh
$ cat file
name,date,time
DEF,01/02/2021,06:00
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:50
```

Then

```bsh
{
  IFS= read -r header
  echo "$header"
  sort -t, -k2.7,2.10n -k2.4,2.5n -k2.1,2.2n -k3,3
} < file
```

```
name,date,time
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,01/02/2021,05:50
DEF,01/02/2021,06:00
```